# Logic error: "bsList()" List changes size unexpectedly

Tags: c#

I copied a queue to a list, " var bsList = bs.ToList();"  Stepping through the code I noticed bsList changes from 47 JSON elements to 37.  I do not see how that is possible. When I get to this line, "var listBuy = bsList;" in the code below, it has less elements.  How is this possible?

```
                // bs queue to list
            var bsList = bs.ToList();

            //get all sell objects in a list
             var listSell = bsList; // **bsList has 47 JSON elements**
            listSell.RemoveAll(s => s.BuySell == "Buy");

            // make the latest sell date object
            DateCloseBuySell lastSell = new DateCloseBuySell();
            lastSell = listSell.Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1.Date > i2.Date ? i1 : i2);

            // remove lastSell object from ListSell
            listSell.RemoveAll(s => s.Date == lastSell.Date);

            // get the new latest sell date object
            DateCloseBuySell lastSell2 = new DateCloseBuySell();
            lastSell2 = listSell.Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1.Date > i2.Date ? i1 : i2);

            // get the buy objects in a list
            var listBuy = bsList; // **shows only 37 elements in bsList**
            listBuy.RemoveAll(s => s.BuySell == "Sell");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it happening because you are assigning reference to other variable and performing operation on it.

```
        var listSell = bsList; // **bsList has 47 JSON elements**
        listSell.RemoveAll(s => s.BuySell == "Buy");
```

here listSell have reference of bsList element , and then updading listSell.

If you dont want that behavior then you should perform copy of list like as below

```
   List<Int32> copy = original.ToList(); //shallow copy
```